# How to build a rubygems mirror server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

My workplace has banned us  from internet access so we can't connect to rubygems.org to install gems remotely.

I can access rubygems.org at home. Is there a simple way to enable me download and update the  gems we need at home ,then sync them(by a portable hard disk or somthing) to a local gems mirror server at my  workplace so that other colleagues can
install gems from that mirror server?

Comment: Where do you work?  That sounds unreasonable!

Comment: haha, forget about gems, what are they gonna do without Google?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [rubygems-mirror](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror) to mirror the gems and [Gem in a box](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/) to host them.

**Install rubygems-mirror:**

```
$ gem install rubygems-mirror
```

**Edit `~/.gem/.mirrorrc`:**

```
---
- from: http://rubygems.org
  to: ~/.gem/mirror
```

**Create mirror dir:**

```
$ mkdir ~/.gem/mirror
```

**Start mirroring:**

```
$ gem mirror
```

**Once mirroring finishes edit `~/.gem/mirror/config.ru`:**

```
require "rubygems"
require "geminabox"

Geminabox.data = "./"
run Geminabox
```

**Install Gem in a box:**

```
$ gem install geminabox
```

**Start gem server:**

```
$ cd ~/.gem/mirror
$ rackup
```

**Edit your application's `Gemfile` to use your gem server:**

```
source "http://your.servers.ip:9292"
.
```

**Or add it as a local [mirror](http://bundler.io/v1.5/bundle_config.html) for rubygems.org, so you don't have to change your `Gemfile`:**

```
$ bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org https://localgems.lan
$ bundle config mirror.http://rubygems.org http://localgems.lan
```

**From time to time reindex your mirror:**

```
$ gem generate_index --directory ~/.gem/mirror
```

Comment: thanks! if I wanna update the mirror,all I need to do is: step 1. $gem mirror; step2.xcopy ~/.gem/mirror at home computer to ~/.gem/mirror at my workplace's local server, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you also need to configure the Gem in a box server and update the sources to point to it.

Comment: how much disk space can I expect this to use? I ask this also concerned about the number of gigabytes that could potentially be downloaded by the mirroring operation.

Also, is this an operation that can be stopped and then resumes where it left? I'm referring to the 'gem mirror' command, of course.

Comment: There are over 44k gems (http://rubygems.org/stats) at the moment which would take up over 100GB of space. I'd recommend against it unless you really need to. The gem mirror command can be aborted and continue where it left off.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the same thing. Can anyone guide me through the stepa @TomCaps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'gem mirror' continuing from where it left of it very reliable. I ran into following issue https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror/issues/22 and I waiting hear back from gem owners