# When RubyGems hangs

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I just had RubyGems not updating for a minute or two on "Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/".

I'm wondering how to prevent this in the future. Is there a reliable RubyGems mirror which I could specify as an additional source in Gemfile? And would it automatically switch over to the new source after a short timeout?

Comment: Don't know any official mirror sites, but you might want to check this one and build your own mirror: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411045/how-to-build-a-rubygems-mirror-server

Comment: What version of bundler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official mirror.  But I discovered that pointing your Gem source to http://production.s3.rubygems.org worked even when I got time-outs from http://rubygems.org

Comment: Thanks though I have to say RubyGems has been very stable for a long time anyway.