# Download all gems and dependancies from github or a seperate server instead of RubyGems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, bundler

My companies networking won't allow us to access almost any site but github, so I'm wondering how I will be able to install gems.

Option 1: point to the github source of all the gems, but wouldn't we also have to specify the dependencies from github as well ?

Option 2: We have a proxy server which has access to RubyGems, and I'm thinking if we can download all the gems and dependencies there then we can source the gems over to that machine. Would I need to literally host the files on that server to point at them from my gemfile?

Are either of those options possible ?

Edit:
I think this question solves my problem: [How to build a rubygems mirror server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411045/how-to-build-a-rubygems-mirror-server)

Comment: maybe just change company - you need to install gems and there is https://rubygems.org/ - if they can not add it, this means it's "bad" company.

Comment: Normally the company is fine, the restriction is due to pci issues.

Comment: ok I have no clue what "pci" means in this context, but any inbound traffic should be fine(responses), the restrictions are important on outbound traffic.

Comment: what kinda of proxy?  since you can tell gem to use an HTTP proxy to access the net, and it will also honor environment variables such as HTTP_PROXY

Answer (score 1):

You can source your gems from 'gems.github.com'. They publish a list of gems that can be sourced from them here: http://gems.github.com/list.html As I understand the list is no longer being updated though, so you'll run into problems eventually.

I guess you could try to run a local mirror. Found this after a quick google: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror

That said, I'm with mpapis. If you are working for a company that wants you to code Ruby and they don't allow use of rubygems.org I'd ask myself some serious questions about whether I'd want to be employed there.