# Any official mirrors of rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm having lately troubles with deploying application, because of errors connected to  rubygems.org, like:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from http://rubygems.org/
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!                                                                        

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize'
Connection timed out - connect(2)
Errno::ETIMEDOUT
```

The gems system is great but I see it as a point of single failure, when it's not available you can't get the newest patches etc. There is a huge network of Debian repositories and the mirror could be selected on geographical location. Is there something similar for gems? And if there is some mirror, how can I be sure that the packages there are not compromised? (which happened recently also to rubygems.org)

Another thing, when I have a local copy of gems, can bundler transfer them directly to server without fetching from rubygems.org? It might reduce load of servers and moreover make sure, that your deploy will work any time (I know, I can check gems into my git repository, but I don't like to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem might solve the issue [capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled](https://github.com/rudionrails/capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled). The usage pretty simple:

`config/deploy.rb:`

```
require 'capistrano-strategy-copy-bundled'
set :deploy_via,    :copy_bundled
```

All your gems are packed on local to a tar archive, which is afterwards transferred to the server. However there's one problem, if you want to deploy gems with native extensions (like database drivers, therubyracer etc.) you need to have same architecture and versions of dependent libraries (like glibc) on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

There may be mirrors of Rubygems.org but I haven't tried them and don't know if they have all the gems.
But there is a declaration in your `Gemfile` called `source` where you can tell Bundler to look on a different mirror.

There is a gem however that can mirror all the gems to your local system called [rubygems-mirror](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems-mirror)

You can install certain gems locally into your git through the Bundler `:path` command.
So if you want to have a local copy of let's say devise you can do

```
gem 'devise', :path => 'vendor/devise'
```

And you then clone the devise repository inside your `vendor/devise` folder and commit that to Git.

It gets really boring really fast though if you try to do that with all Gems as there are dozens of gems only involved in Rails itself. You can look at RVM Gemsets for that and there is a way for bundler to get all gems and bundle them with your application (sorry you'll have to consult the doc for further info as I haven't needed that yet)

Comment: It could be a caching mirror, just keeping copies of most recently used gems and forwarding other request to rubygems.org. I don't like relying on just one source, most of the servers are located probably in the USA, it would be nice to have something in Europe. Yeah, I don't want to checkout gems to git repository, I would prefer packing all gems at local to one archive and send it to a server. It's possible to do it with JRuby (you create just one `war` file).

Comment: This question may help you with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411045/how-to-build-a-rubygems-mirror-server Seems thorough..

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of github, if the gem is available there. Rubyforge is very popular though. As far as i know, your gemfile must be declared properly, see if you have some version conflicts with the gem/s if you have single ruby and/or rails installation.

Comment: Then I would rely on availability of github, which doesn't solve anything. Sure, I have some cutting-edge versions of gems from github, but most of them are from rubygems.org.

Comment: A few months ago, i faced an issue, while installing databasedotcom-salseforce gem, and it was available both at ruby-forge and github, none of them worked, i then had to work around the gemfile, and it was having all the problems.