# How to install Ruby on Rails using LAN Connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one system with open Internet and other system in same network under proxy where I can't access most of the sites. And it is almost impossible to use for installing rvm and rails. I can install rvm in one machine which have open internet, can anyone give me idea how to install RVM and rails in one machine and do clone same thing in other machine. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any effort will be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can setup a ruby gem mirror server like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411045/how-to-build-a-rubygems-mirror-server

Answer (score 0):

I got the multiple solution and one of the best solution using apt-cacher-ng. I used this and it all worked fine.